# Regexp matched values subpattern as subarray

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/oF7pM8/1
I get http://joxi.ru/J2b54KaI40bbwm
But, i have get all "num" values (all digits) and that they are in an array "num"
I have to get it:
name = house
num = [3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
What's wrong doing?
p.s.: python regular expression

**The pattern must find all the numbers separately (array).**

Comment: The `?` makes the repetition lazy, this is why it matches just one digit. Check the [updated version](https://regex101.com/r/oF7pM8/2)

Comment: Then the last digit is found, not all. I need all.

Answer (score 0):

Does `(?P<name>house)(?:\s(?P<num>(\d\s+)+)\d?)+?` do the job ?

My additions to your original in bold: (?Phouse)(?:\s(?P**(\d\s+)+**)**\d?**)+?

Comment: This pattern is not suitable, since it does not find all the numbers individually (array).

Comment: Please add this requirement to your post, and I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Then the last digit is found, not all. I need all.

`re.match` *finds* all, but *returns* only the last one. Since you have to post-process the matches anyway in order to assign them to the Python variables `name` and `num`, make the pattern simple:

```
import re
test_string = 'house 3 44 555 6666 777 88 9'
m = re.match(r'(house)((\s\d+)+)', test_string)
name = m.group(1)
num = [int(s) for s in m.group(2).split()]
```